# i can't scroll my form when my listbox has a focus

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

In Access 2007 form if any of my listboxs has a focus, I can;t scroll my form up or down. To do that I have to move the focus to any other control except the listbox, and by the way all of my listboxs have only 4 items on it with no scroll bar, I just need to use my mouse scroll wheel to scroll up or down my whole form even if my listbox has a focus.

I have found the following code that is used to disable the listbox scroll, but I couldn't test it because I can't see any event named (mousewheel) in my listbox events list.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
Handles ListBox1.MouseWheel
Dim disable As HandledMouseEventArgs = e
disable.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Also I don't know if that code will force my form to use its scroll instead of the listbox scroll. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless I'm very mistaken, that'd be VB.NET code; won't fly in VBA

Comment: so is there any alternative ??

Comment: I don't know ... not an Access user, and as I recall, Access forms are a bit different from other VBA forms.  Just wanted to comment as to why you were having troubles with that particular code.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. From an MS point of view, they want people using their software (even if it's your software running inside theirs) to get a consistent experience. Access is a bit too primitive to be overriding control behavior.
There might be ways you can redesign the form if users are getting lost (personally I hate scrolling forms - I favour a bit of a wizard approach, where the users are asked a small amount of questions at a time and forms for displaying info compartmentalise the info so the user isn't swamped with data).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is remove focus from listbox to a textbox instead.

1. Place textbox near listbox and format it as follows:

   - Under "Data" tab: `Enabled = Yes; Locked = Yes`
   - Under "Format" tab: `Width = 0`

   Textbox must be enabled in order to receive focus. Also "Locked = Yes" should prevent any entry. Now placing it next to listbox serves as a placholder for scrolling when the textbox control receive focus
2. Next hook a "click" event to Detail. Example:

   ```
   Private Sub Detail_Click()

       select case(me.ActiveControl.Name)
           case "your list box name":  Me.myDummyTextbox.SetFocus
           '
           ' add more case as needed 
           '
       end select
   End Sub
   ```